# how to split one redis instance into two?

Tags: redis

I have a redis as big as 4G on one 4G memory machine,I want to split it into two 2G redis instance so that I can run the two on two different machines.

how to do that?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy way to do it.

One way to do it is to use the redis-rdb-tools package from Sripathi Krishnan. The procedure is:

- choose a strategy to shard your data (i.e a function which distributes the keys over the instances)
- write a Python script to parse a Redis dump file, connect to several instances, and apply the commands to insert the data on the correct instances
- dump the Redis instance
- flush the instance
- create and start the second instance
- run the script on the dump of the first instance

See more information at https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

Answer (score 1):

you can use redis cluster

> Redis Cluster provides a way to run a Redis installation where data is
>   automatically sharded across multiple Redis nodes.
>
> Every Redis Cluster node requires two TCP connections open.

http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial